# Ansible: Error "Line has invalid autocommand"

Tags: ansible

I just installed Ansible and trying a simple ping but getting errors.
below is the output of the command:

```json
test-switch | FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to test-switch closed.\r\n",
    "module_stdout": "\r\nLine has invalid autocommand \"/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python '\"'\"'Line has invalid autocommand \"/bin/sh -c '\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p \"` echo Line has invalid autocommand \"/bin/sh -c '\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'echo ~**** && sleep 0'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 0
}
```

Here is some extra info:

```bash
user@server:~$ sudo ansible test -m ping -i test-hosts -vvv
ansible [core 2.13.3]
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /root/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.10.4 (main, Jun 29 2022, 12:14:53) [GCC 11.2.0]
  jinja version = 3.0.3
  libyaml = True
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
host_list declined parsing /home/user/test-hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /home/user/test-hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /home/user/test-hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Parsed /home/user/test-hosts inventory source with ini plugin
Skipping callback 'default', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'minimal', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'oneline', as we already have a stdout callback.
META: ran handlers
<test-switch> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ****
<test-switch> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d10 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'User="****"' -o ConnectTimeout=30 -o 'ControlPath="/root/.ansible/cp/e7f6d09650"' test-switch '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~**** && sleep 0'"'"''
<test-switch> (0, b'\r\nLine has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c \'echo ~**** && sleep 0\'"', b'')
<test-switch> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ****
<test-switch> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d10 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'User="****"' -o ConnectTimeout=30 -o 'ControlPath="/root/.ansible/cp/e7f6d09650"' test-switch '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo ~**** && sleep 0'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo ~**** && sleep 0'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1662641931.939476-3032-59266234632066 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1662641931.939476-3032-59266234632066="` echo Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo ~**** && sleep 0'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1662641931.939476-3032-59266234632066 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<test-switch> (0, b'\r\nLine has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c \'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c \'"\'"\'echo ~**** && sleep 0\'"\'"\'"/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c \'"\'"\'echo ~**** && sleep 0\'"\'"\'"/.ansible/tmp/a"', b'')
<test-switch> Attempting python interpreter discovery
<test-switch> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ****
<test-switch> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d10 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'User="****"' -o ConnectTimeout=30 -o 'ControlPath="/root/.ansible/cp/e7f6d09650"' test-switch '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo PLATFORM; uname; echo FOUND; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.10'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.9'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.8'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.7'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.6'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.5'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/bin/python3'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/libexec/platform-python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python2.7'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/bin/python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; echo ENDFOUND && sleep 0'"'"''
<test-switch> (0, b'\r\nLine has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c \'echo PLATFORM; uname; echo FOUND; command -v \'"\'"\'python3.10\'"\'"\'; command -v \'"\'"\'python3.9\'"\'"\'; command -v \'"\'"\'python3.8\'"\'"\'; command -v \'"\'"\'python3.7\'"\'"\'; command -v \'"\'"\'python3.6\'"\'"\'; command -v \'"\'"\'python3.5\'"\'"\'; command -v \'"\'"\'"', b'')
[WARNING]: Unhandled error in Python interpreter discovery for host test-switch: unexpected output from Python interpreter discovery
Using module file /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible/modules/ping.py
<test-switch> PUT /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-3029qijo7fpq/tmp0dni2qsr TO Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~**** && sleep 0'"'"'"/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~**** && sleep 0'"'"'"/.ansible/tmp/a"/AnsiballZ_ping.py
<test-switch> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d10 sftp -o BatchMode=no -b - -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'User="****"' -o ConnectTimeout=30 -o 'ControlPath="/root/.ansible/cp/e7f6d09650"' '[test-switch]'
[WARNING]: sftp transfer mechanism failed on [test-switch]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information
<test-switch> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d10 scp -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'User="****"' -o ConnectTimeout=30 -o 'ControlPath="/root/.ansible/cp/e7f6d09650"' /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-3029qijo7fpq/tmp0dni2qsr '[test-switch]:'"'"'Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo ~**** && sleep 0'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo ~**** && sleep 0'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"/.ansible/tmp/a"/AnsiballZ_ping.py'"'"''
[WARNING]: scp transfer mechanism failed on [test-switch]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information
<test-switch> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ****
<test-switch> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d10 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'User="****"' -o ConnectTimeout=30 -o 'ControlPath="/root/.ansible/cp/e7f6d09650"' test-switch 'dd of=Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo ~**** && sleep 0'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo ~**** && sleep 0'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"/.ansible/tmp/a"/AnsiballZ_ping.py bs=65536'
<test-switch> (0, b'\r\nLine has invalid autocommand "dd of=Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c \'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c \'"\'"\'echo ~**** && sleep 0\'"\'"\'"/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c \'"\'"\'echo ~svc_ansib"', b'')
<test-switch> (0, b'\r\nLine has invalid autocommand "dd of=Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c \'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c \'"\'"\'echo ~**** && sleep 0\'"\'"\'"/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c \'"\'"\'echo ~svc_ansib"', b'')
<test-switch> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ****
<test-switch> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d10 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'User="****"' -o ConnectTimeout=30 -o 'ControlPath="/root/.ansible/cp/e7f6d09650"' test-switch '/bin/sh -c '"'"'chmod u+x '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo ~**** && sleep 0'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo ~**** && sleep 0'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"/.ansible/tmp/a"/'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo ~**** && sleep 0'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo ~**** && sleep 0'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"/.ansible/tmp/a"/AnsiballZ_ping.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
<test-switch> (0, b'\r\nLine has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c \'chmod u+x \'"\'"\'Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c \'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c \'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'echo ~**** && sleep 0\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"', b'')
<test-switch> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ****
<test-switch> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d10 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'User="****"' -o ConnectTimeout=30 -o 'ControlPath="/root/.ansible/cp/e7f6d09650"' -tt test-switch '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo ~**** && sleep 0'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo ~**** && sleep 0'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"/.ansible/tmp/a"/AnsiballZ_ping.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
<test-switch> (0, b'\r\nLine has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c \'/usr/bin/python \'"\'"\'Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c \'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c \'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"\'echo ~**** && sleep 0\'"\'"\'"\'"\'"', b'Shared connection to test-switch closed.\r\n')
[WARNING]: Platform unknown on host test-switch is using the discovered Python interpreter at /usr/bin/python, but future installation of another Python interpreter could change the meaning of that path. See
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-core/2.13/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information.
test-switch | FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to test-switch closed.\r\n",
    "module_stdout": "\r\nLine has invalid autocommand \"/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python '\"'\"'Line has invalid autocommand \"/bin/sh -c '\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p \"` echo Line has invalid autocommand \"/bin/sh -c '\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"'echo ~**** && sleep 0'\"'\"'\"'\"'\"",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 0
}
user@server:~$
```

Comment: According the output provided it seems that you try to establish a SSH connection to a switch. Such devices may not have all capabilities for Python scripts. Therefore you may need to provide more details about your target devices, playbook, etc..

Comment: I'm just trying to ping, not sure why it's trying ssh

Comment: Because of [`ping` module – Try to connect to host, verify a usable python and return pong on success](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ping_module.html) "_This is NOT ICMP ping, this is just a trivial test module that requires Python on the remote-node._".

Comment: thanks!!! I'll try to find other way to ping

Answer (score 0):

the command actually works when I add some extra info in the inventory file

these are the lines I added:

```
ansible_connection=network_cli
ansible_network_os=ios
ansible_port=22
```

and the ping worked:

```
user@server:~$ ansible test -m ping -i test-hosts
[WARNING]: ansible-pylibssh not installed, falling back to paramiko
test-switch | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
```